# Is there a well defined way to shift Cauchy surfaces back and forth?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Let $S$ be a Cauchy surface on a four-dimensional connected Lorentzian manifold.

Define $\Gamma(S)=\{\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to M\mid \gamma(0)\in S, \gamma$ is a unit speed geodesic passing orthogonally through $S\}$.

Do the sets of the form $\{\gamma(x) \mid \gamma\in\Gamma(S)\}$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ define a foliation of space-time into Cauchy surfaces? (I.e. could sets of this form fail to be Cauchy surfaces, or could they fail to completely foliate the manifold?)